# Deleted comment - just gone

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-comments

I would like to know why my comments are deleted:

[Why won't Israel just capture Palestine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/why-wont-israel-just-capture-palestine)

I have commented the Chad answer...

I didn't get notify or something. I cannot see my old comment anywhere. 
Nothing. Just gone.

Comment: I just had the same experience. I made a comment that was critical of Israel. The next day the comment was gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment thread was getting too long and it was beginning to go off topic.

The Stack Exchange format is for Questions and Answers to those questions, and the purpose of comments is to supplement that.  Long discussions in the comments that aren't specifically about the question or answer will be deleted.

Comments begin to become noise, that casual visitors probably aren't here for, and we strive to minimize the noise here.

Don't feel like you were singled out there.  there are at least 10 deleted comments on that answer.

Comment: thanks. It makes sense. However...
> can I at least read my deleted messages?
> could the system notify the user before removing?

Comment: @rdllopes comments are second-class citizens.  If it were questions/answers, you can see them, and you could navigate to them by going to the list of questions or the list of answers from your profile

Comment: ok. I got it. 
> comment as second-class citizen... After that I think it is crystal clear that is a terrible idea. Stackexchange can disagree, but my experience was not good at all.

Comment: @rdllopes it helps to remember that StackExchange sites aren't discussion forums. They're more like FAQs.

Comment: Agree. But, as here we are clarifying the answer. This FAQ is made by people. So, it should be good to help the users improve the quality of site. For instance, I would like to see my deleted comments. it would be easier to create a new question based on my comments... my suggestion: stack could or keep the comments or send a message before removing comments.

Comment: @rdllopes On SE, there's almost always a better way to communicate than comments. Take your comment here, for example. It is highly unlikely that anyone from SE will ever read it, thus the chances for your suggestion to make it into the system are slim to none. If you take the time to open a new [feature-request] meta question about it, on the other hand, it's almost guaranteed that someone from SE will see and evaluate it (SE employees regularly check for unresolved [feature-request] questions).

Comment: @rdllopes It's a bit of shock realising that comments on Stack Exchange are transient (for context negotiations and local flavour) if you don't already know this; as it isn't particularly well advertised. So if you have any truly pithy insights or elegant prose you want to preserve for self-edification, I'd suggest writing and saving them in notepad first.